# concat sequence next value with string

Tags: java, jsp, oracle10g, sequence

i want the sequence next value to be inserted into table after concatenating with some string value. eg: case12. Here 'case' will be the string and '12' will be the next sequence value.
i'm trying this code in my jsp page.

```
String name=request.getParameter("name").toString();
 String pwd=request.getParameter("pass").toString();
out.print(name+" and "+pwd);
String add="case";
 PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement("insert into test(caseid,userid,pass) values('CONCAT('"+add+"',test_seq.nextval)',?,?)");
            ps.setString(1,name);
            ps.setString(2,pwd);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            connect.commit();
            connect.close();
```

but, i'm getting this error `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00917: missing comma`

can anybody tell me the solution for above problem. Any help appreciated.!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If at all possible, you should prefer passing in parameters to dynamically assembling a SQL statement.  So if you don't want "case" to be a hard-coded constant, it ought to be a bind variable.

Additionally, you don't want single-quotes around the `CONCAT` call.  Something like this should work.

```
String name=request.getParameter("name").toString();
String pwd=request.getParameter("pass").toString();
out.print(name+" and "+pwd);
String add="case";
String sqlStmt = "insert into test(caseid,userid,pass) values(CONCAT(?,test_seq.nextval),?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);
ps.setString(1,add);
ps.setString(2,name);
ps.setString(3,pwd);
ps.executeUpdate();
connect.commit();
connect.close();
```

Comment: thanks..!! it works...:) 
but, it should be ps.setString(1,add); not ps.setString(1,case);
but, that's not a big issue. thanks for your help

Comment: @sql_query - Yup, sorry about that.  Changed it to use the proper variable name.